# Viewing the cognitive complexity of all methods in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse, cognitive-complexity

Is it possible to view the "Cognitive complexity" for all methods in **Eclipse** irrespective of whether it exceeds the limit or not using `SonarLint` plugin

One workaround I used was to reduce the limit to 0 in `Windows -> Preferences -> SonarLint -> Rules Configuration`. But the issue of this approach is that, it would generate that amount of sonar warnings.

So is there any way to see the Cognitive complexity of methods that have not yet exceeded the limit?

Even though it would be easier to calculate it manually for such methods, but if there is such a functionality, then it would be easy to track those methods which are very close to the limit.